# Calculate sum Revenue for the same fiscal Period last year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a period(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) slicer and year(2018,2019,2020) and will like to calculate the sum of revenue for last year for the same Period that the user pick Vs the Revenue this year for that period.

Now using sameperiodaslast year function won't work because I am using fiscal periods and the start date/end date of the same period is not the same.

If i use year -1 it gets me the result I am looking for but when I select all periods it does a full year vs this year revenue stops at today's number.

Any idea how to stop last year revenue in the same day as today -1 year.

Comment: What are you fiscal periods if they're not months, is it something like a 4-4-5 type calendar?

Comment: yes, it is 4-4-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by limiting current date for last year date< Current date -1 year, so now the revenue from start of the year till today's date will have the same period last year start date till today last year.